# SQL condition if doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

so I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    p.ID
FROM 
    `cdlr_posts` p, 
    cdlr_postmeta pm 
WHERE 
    pm.post_id=p.ID AND 
    `post_type` = 'shop_order' AND
    pm.meta_key = '_statusCDLR' AND
    pm.meta_value <> 1 
group by
    p.ID
```

What I need is to show all the IDS if they match with those conditions, but I will also like to show the ones that do not contain the "_statusCDLR" `meta_key` I tried something like this with no luck:

```
WHERE 
    pm.post_id=p.ID AND 
    `post_type` = 'shop_order' AND
    (pm.meta_key = '_statusCDLR' AND pm.meta_value <> 1 OR pm.meta_key <> '_statusCDLR') 
group by
```

Any help will be appreciated to achieve what I need.

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: (1) Implicit joins have been generally recognized as inferior to explicit ones for decades, (2) always force precedence on boolean operators like OR and AND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that your requirement is to select the `id` of `posts` that :

- *either* have a corresponding record in `cdlr_post_meta` with `meta_key = 'statusCDLR'` and `meta_value <> 1`
- *or* do not have a record `cdlr_post_meta` with `meta_key = 'statusCDLR'`

A strategy to achieve this is to use a `LEFT JOIN` to search for a record in `cdlr_post_meta` with `meta_key = 'statusCDLR'`, and then implement the rest of the logic in the `WHERE` clause (if there is no corresponding record, the columns of `pm` are all `NULL`).

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM cdlr_posts p
LEFT JOIN cdlr_postmeta pm 
    ON pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key = '_statusCDLR'
WHERE 
    p.post_type = 'shop_order'
    AND ( pm.post_id IS NULL OR pm.meta_value <> 1 )
GROUP BY p.ID
```

PS - General remarks regarding your sql :

- When mixing  `OR`s and `AND`s, you need to surround the test expressions within parentheses to avoid running into prescedence issues (`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`).
- you should use explicit `JOIN`s instead of implicit ones.

Comment: @Ered : I changed the query, please check again.

Comment: I tried ur code but ID is still showing even if meta_key =_statusCDLR and meta_value = 1

Comment: seams the problem is here : `OR (
            pm.meta_key <> '_statusCDLR'
        )` if I remove that line it works but im back to square 1

Comment: @Ered : this query does not select records where meta_key is statusCDLR and meta_value is 1... Maybe check your test data ?

Comment: my goal is to show ID's that contain `meta_key=statusCDLR` AND `meta_value=0` OR if `meta_key=statusCDLR` does not exist, think you can help me out, as you see im using wordpress structure...with your query it still shows ID if meta_value=1 and it shouldn't.

Comment: @Ered so basically you just want to exclude records where meta_key is statusCDLR and meta_value is 1 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186809/discussion-between-ered-and-gmb).